# How to get joint velocity from Moveit 2 Robot State?

Tags: ros, moveit, joint-states

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to get the velocity of each joint using Moveit 2 Robot State? Is there any better approach?

I tried the following:

```
robot_model_loader::RobotModelLoader robot_model_loader(node);
const moveit::core::RobotModelPtr& kinematic_model = robot_model_loader.getModel();
const moveit::core::JointModelGroup* joint_model_group = kinematic_model->getJointModelGroup("my_arm");
const moveit::core::RobotState current_robot_state = moveit::core::RobotState(kinematic_model);

auto velocities = current_robot_state.getVariableVelocities();
// velocities = garbage

std::vector<double> actualVelocity;
current_robot_state.copyJointGroupVelocities(joint_model_group, actualVelocity);
// actualVelocity = garbage also
```

I can get the joints positions without any problem. The velocity is published to `/joint_states` topic correctly.

The only solution is subscribe to `/joint_states`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/417132/how-to-get-joint-velocity-from-moveit-2-robot-state?/) by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2023-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I manually set the velocity from joint_states topic

---

Originally posted by [mth_sousa](https://answers.ros.org/users/103087/mth_sousa/) with karma: 35 on 2023-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0